# Where to check swarm load balancer logs?

Tags: python, docker, nginx, haproxy, swarm

I have docker compose file as

```
---
version: '3.7'
services:
  myapi:
    image: tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.7
    env_file: apivars.env
    logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        syslog-address: "udp://127.0.0.1:514"
        tag: tags
        labels: labels
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role != manager
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 32
      update_config:
        parallelism: 4
        delay: 5s
        order: start-first
...
```

I have load balancer which will redirect request to this swarm manager.

My understanding is, if I hit `www.myapi.com`, it will got to LoadBalancer and then request will go to swarm manager, then swarm manager send that request to on of the `32` replicas.

Now issue is, LoadBalancer logs report some of the 502 errors.

```
# head -n1 /var/log/haproxy.log
Apr 28 09:35:28 localhost haproxy[43117]: 172.19.9.1:50220 [28/Apr/2020:09:35:08.549] main~ API_Production/swarmnode5 0/0/1/19952/19953 502 309 - - ---- 97/97/10/1/0 0/0 "GET /v2/students/?includeFields=name,id&per_page=1000&page=88 HTTP/1.1"
```

I have to check its reaching to swarm manager or swarmnode5 ?

I check the logs for `nginx`, but its not report any 502 errors. There are some exceptions, but not sure if exception is there in code, then why `nginx` not logs that api call and response?